# How do I avoid having to compute square roots for every element in a data set?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

I have a list of points, with floating point coordinates, of which I've computed the square of the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between these points. I have not computed the actual Euclidean distance between these points because computing a square root is an expensive operation. So, I have a list of floating point squares `{a², b²...}`.

My goal is to find the arithmetic mean of the actual Euclidean distance values, `(a + b + ...) / n)`.

Is there a way to avoid computing square root for every element?

Comment: Do you know anything else about the data? The standard deviation, for example, would help.

Comment: The thing that came to my mind is that STDEV[X] = sqrt(E[X²] - E[X]²) so if you know two of the quantities, you can compute the third. But I don't have any other idea.

Comment: Possibly more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's the application for using the mean? Is it possible that some other kind of average will suffice (eg root-mean-square, which would clearly be trivial to calculate)?

Comment: Client wants the mean...

Comment: He wants RMS too, but I have that done already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to know the **exact** answer, you should read this paper:

http://www2.mta.ac.il/~adish/Pubs/Papers/av-metric-r3.pdf ([archive.org link to prevent link rot](http://web.archive.org/web/20151015144841/http://www2.mta.ac.il/~adish/Pubs/Papers/av-metric-r3.pdf))

First, it's clear from the paper that there is no way to do this to get an exact answer that's faster than the brute force approach:

> Our aim is beating the obvious algorithm that computes the exact value of the
>   aforementioned average (by considering all pairs of points). But, unlike in the
>   graph theoretic setting (cf. [4]), we cannot hope for approximation algorithms
>   that run in time that is sub-linear in the number of points (because a single
>   “exceptional” point may dominate the value of the average of all pairwise distances).
>   Thus, we seek approximation algorithms that run in time that is almost
>   linear in the number of points. We consider two algorithmic approaches.

Then they have an easy answer: rather than computing the Euclidean distance for all pairs of points, you can get a `sqrt(d)` approximation by averaging the distances of the coordinates (unfortunately, Programmers.SE doesn't have MathJax so a screenshot will have to do):

[image]

tl;dr math language: basically the formula is just saying add all the pairs of distances between the coordinates. For example, `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)` just becomes `x2 - x1 + y2 - y1`, and your answer will only be off by a factor of `sqrt(d)`, which in this case is `sqrt(2)`.

Then, the paper goes on to discuss a **random sampling algorithm**, which is more accurate.

[image: Random sampling]

I recommend reading the paper to see why this works, they explain it better than I can.

Answer (score 10):

**1. change presentation data**

Don't save squares but the square roots when inserting them, since `a*a` is cheaper than `sqrt(aa)`

**2. fixed cache**

*I assume that just integers are used.*

If you know, that there are many duplicates, maybe between `1*1` and `1000*1000` e.g. than caching them in a hashmap might accelerate computation.

**3. LRU-cache**

If you know that there are many duplicates in it, then a LRU-Cache might help you.

**4. approximation**

Instead of using `sqrt` you could implement it yourself, but only with a few iterations.

Comment: Thats not an answer I'm afraid. Only cache may be considered as an answer (not for me though).

Comment: 1. you're writing in programmers stackexchange. If you want a mathematical solution then write in http://math.stackexchange.com/. 2. `Is there a way to avoid computing square root for every element?` and there is your answer.

Comment: @pacholik It *is* an answer. That it does not suit you has partially to do with the fact that you did not give enough background in your question, which had to be pulled from you through comments (and you did not even bother to update the question with your comment answers - all relevant info should be *in* the original question). This is like moving the goal posts during the game.

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it's clear from the question that the distances are **not integers**, so caching will not help. period.

Comment: @durron597 it was **not** clear some hours ago ! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/299930/revisions

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how exact your average needs to be. If there is a large disparity between the size of the cubes you can "ignore" the smaller cubes and not calculate their sqrt and still get a good average estimate:

```
(1000 + 1000 + 1000 + 0.001) / 4 = 750.00025
```

Ignore the last value:

```
(1000 + 1000 + 1000 + 0) / 4 = 750
```

Comment: @GlenH7 I actually live in a country where we use a `,` as decimal separator.  However, in no locale is the `.` used for `0.001` and the `,` for `750,00025`. Mixing separators inside a single expression is extremely confusing.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a way to avoid computing square root for every element?*

Absolutely. Raise the value to the power of ½.

*Great. Is this faster?*

It is a [well trodden road](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332750/why-is-square-root-such-a-slow-operation), but unfortunately I have yet to find any language, platform or CPU where the default implementation of such is more efficient.

Various [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) exist if you wanted to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Aitch proposed using a cache if you have integers, but you stated you have floats. A cache is however still possible if:

- the points whose distance you are calculating are on a grid (so the set of likely values is small)

- or -

- the resulting value does not need high accuracy (in which case you may use *intervals* as keys in your cache).

In the second case, if you keep pairs (a²;b²) → (a;b) with a and b close, you can also get a lower and upper bound on the average, if that's useful to the client. (It would be helpful to mention what that average is needed for)